# Does log4cplus library supporting c++_shared runtime library for Android

Tags: android, c++, logging, shared-libraries, log4cplus

i am compiling log4cplus library for android & it needs c++ runtime STL library. as per

https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/blob/master/android/android.toolchain.cmake

**line number: 835-837 are as follow:**

```
if( BUILD_WITH_ANDROID_NDK )
  if( NOT "${ANDROID_STL}" MATCHES "^(none|system|system_re|gabi\\+\\+_static|gabi\\+\\+_shared|stlport_static|stlport_shared|gnustl_static|gnustl_shared)$")
  message( FATAL_ERROR "ANDROID_STL is set to invalid value \"${ANDROID_STL}\".
```

it is not supporting c++_shared & c++_static runtime library, How to add these two library Support in log4cplus for Android?

Comment: Feel free to try to update the `android.toolchain.cmake` from https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake and try it. I, the maintainer of log4cplus, have no knowledge of Android development.  Let me know if you succeed and how.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the `android.toolchain.cmake` file with the [one from OpenCV](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake). I will update the log4cplus copy later.

Comment: facing lots of error::
-  #error <atomic> is not implemented 
-  error: '::iswblank' has not been declared

Comment: i am using android-ndk-r9d for native support

Comment: @Nishant: I have no idea.